# Problem with lldb-mi and Eclipse on MacOs

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging

I installed lldb-mi following the [documentation](https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi). At the moment I have the executable in the directory "/usr/local/bin/lldb-mi", and when I launch it I get the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4PWS.png) output.

I configured Eclipse for C++ to choose lldb-mi for the [debugging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F). I have no errors, but debugging doesn't start. It just seems to build, how could I fix [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrfkf.png)?

Update: I launched the application from the terminal and when I start debugging it tells me: Unable to find full path for "/usr/local/bin/lldb". In fact lldb is located in the folder "/usr/bin/lldb. Is it possible to move the executable?
I copied the executable, but the dubugger still does not work....

Thanks in advance for the answers.