# Could not start debugger. Could not run 'lldb-mi'. Make sure that the path name is specified correctly

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb, kdevelop

I'm facing this error when launching the C++ debug on KDevelop.

Where does this error originate? Any idea would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do you have lldb installed?

Comment: Similar, definitely not-a-dup, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639849/problem-with-lldb-mi-and-eclipse-on-macos

Comment: Snarkily, line 357 of the current source for KDevelop (file plugins/debuggercommon/midebugger.cpp). I'd suggest chasing @AlanBirtles suggestion first. You might have a versioned lldb-mi (e.g. lldb-mi90) installed, or it might be somewhere surprising (e.g. llvm90/bin/lldb-mi). If your system allows it, try making sure `lldb-mi` from the command-line does something useful, for instance, by adding a shell-script wrapper or a symlink.

Comment: @AlanBirtles @AdriaandeGroot I had `lldb` version 13 installed, but it was still not working. So I installed a package named `lldb-mi-git` from AUR, and now the debugger is working. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing `lldb-mi-git` AUR package.

```
paru -S lldb-mi-git
```